# Forcing app to exit via a crash in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can exit apps a few valid ways

```
system("killall SpringBoard");
close(0);
```

But I want to force the app to exit when i detect its been pirated. Its very easy and possibly even automated to remove commands like this with the cracking tools. If I caused the app to exit via a crash from the invalid selector error would it cause the app to fail the review process from Apple?

Obviously it wont crash during testing if I implement the crack protection properly.

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: I honestly wouldn't worry about it. The time and effort you will put into it will quickly escalate and cost more than the actual revenue lost from pirating (not that you actually lose revenue from pirating, as generally people who pirate your app would never have bought it in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly put the pirating detection in, Apple won't even notice that there is anything different about your app when you submit it for review. Maybe instead of crashing your app you would like you show an alert view that says "Your device is jailbroken. You cannot use this app until you restore your device with iTunes."?

Comment: If an App told me that it dislikes my decision to jailbreak my iPhone, I would request an refund from Apple for it asap. Jailbreak != Cracked apps!

Comment: Some people who may have a jailbroken device might not pirate. So I cant take the chance on that. Also if I have a a string in my app that triggers on detection that that the app has been pirated then it will be easier for the crackers to find the code that detects the pirated-app and disable it. Making the app exit via a crash is possibly best solution. I am wondering would the invalid-selector crash trigger Apple to reject the app on the 'Private Api' or some similar rejection reason.

Comment: Sorry, I meant say it was cracked, not jailbroken. I commonly associate the two together by accident.